# Scala partial list of previous elements

Tags: list, scala

Let's say we have:

```
val abc = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

And we want to produce List of 5 Lists where each ot those include all previous elements including current one like:

```
//res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(1,2), List(1,2,3), List(1,2,3,4), List(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Honestlly I tried with `scanleft`, `foldLeft` and `reduceLeft` but can not find appropriate function solution. I come from Java world and staill having soem issues with functional thinking.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 val abc = List(1,2,3,4,5)

 val v = abc.scanLeft(List[Int]()){(a, acc)=> a++ List(acc)}.tail
```

Answer (score 2):

More skinned cats:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5).inits.toList.reverse.tail
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

scala> val is = List(1,2,3,4,5)
is: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> ((List.empty[List[Int]], List.empty[Int]) /: is) {
     | case ((all, cur), i) => val next = cur :+ i ; ((all :+ next, next)) }
res3: (List[List[Int]], List[Int]) = (List(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)),List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

scala> (List(List(is.head)) /: is.tail) {
     | case (all, i) => all :+ (all.last :+ i) }
res4: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(1, 2), List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a perhaps ham-fisted solution that might be more obvious to read:

```
(1 to abc.length).map(abc.take).toList
```

Comment: By the way, It is much slower then `scanLeft` variant.

Comment: @DaunnC Why? The ++ operation is linear in acc.length, so it's going to be quadratic either way.

Comment: yes, you right, there was a sort of bug or smth else on my machine (need more research) in Scala 2.10.3 , sorry for not complete comment.